# Meteor Restart server forcefully manually from the method of server

Tags: meteor, meteor-methods

I want to restart the application from the method of server

I tried by `process.exit(1);` but it stops the execution but not restart the server.

and before that i want to change the default database of the system

if i try by

```
process.env.MONGO_URL = "mongodb://localhost:27017/test"
```

Then it updates the database url even if on refresh of the page it gives me the `mongodb://localhost:27017/test` in server but it uses the `mongodb://localhost:3001/meteor`

how can i use my new connected database and set all the default collections in new database?

Answer (score 1):

Try `process.exit(0);` — it should just restart the server. Exit code `1` will force server to wait for file changes.

**Added:** I've tried it myself and this code is working for me:

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
  Meteor.methods({
    restartApp() {
      process.nextTick(() => {
        process.exit(0);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Ok, let's do that right way. Why do you need to restart your meteor app?

Comment: i have a multiple domains in my system
so i want separate database per domain and use same code

so before i restart meteor i want to set a new database and want to restart my application for new domain so it will use new database for new domian

Comment: Updated my answer regarding app restart

Comment: it occurs continuously and when i restart my sever to interrupt the execution then  gives error on server side that

Exception in callback of async function: Error: listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:27017

and application is not start

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow you here

Comment: Thanks for giving time